# How to customize the the POLL UI and Announcement UI in Windows 8.1 app using C# and xaml?

Tags: win-universal-app, azure-mobile-engagement

I have implemented ME in Windows Universal 8.1 app. When i create any announcement or any poll it appears in the black screen in the app like below.
[image]

But i want to change this UI as per my requirements. How can i change this?

Anybody please help me with a sample code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have a sample for this but you will find the place to customize the appearance on the client side in the "Resources" folder of the SDK in your Windows app solution.

1) Use html/EngagementNotification.html & overlay/EngagementOverlayNotification.xaml to change the base notification which shows up when you set up the campaign from the server side. You can add company logo/branding, images, change the size, orientation etc.

2) Use html/EngagementAnnouncement.html & overlay/EngagementOverlayAnnouncement.xaml to change the subsequent announcement that gets displayed in the form of poll or text or web announcement. Again you can change look and feel etc.

If you are sending a web announcement from the service where you can specify the HTML in the content of your announcement then the HTML content you send from the service gets merged with the HTML you have customized on your client and will be presented such.

Hope this helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Piyush for your reply